# Angular issue with setInterval

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, setinterval, nan

I have this code:

```
export class GameControlComponent {
  @Output() counterUpdated = new EventEmitter<{counter: number, type: string}>();
  @Output() counterStop = new EventEmitter();
  counterSet: any;
  counterStart: number = 0;
   
  startCount() {
    console.log('counter is ' + this.counterStart);
    this.counterSet = setInterval(this.updateCount, 1000);
    //this.updateCount();
  }

  updateCount() {
    this.counterStart += 1;
    console.log('New counter is ' + this.counterStart);
    this.counterUpdated.emit({
      counter: this.counterStart, 
      type: (this.counterStart % 2) === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'
    });  
  }
```

I have a button in html component that listen to this: `(click)='startCount()'`.
Now, if I use `this.updateCount()` (commented above), everything goes fine, and each time I press the button the `counterStart` is updated in the method `updateCount`.
If use `this.counterSet = setInterval(this.updateCount, 1000)`, `counterStart` in `updateCount` becomes `NaN`.

Why? Any idea?

@snak `setInterval(this.updateCount.bind(this), 1000)` this is working fine, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `this.updateCount` to `setInterval` this way, `this` in `updateCount()` will not be `this` in `startCount()` and `counterStart` will be `undefined`.

As `undefined + 1` is `NaN`, it'll print `NaN`.

You can change it to `setInterval(this.updateCount.bind(this), 1000)` or `setInterval(() => this.updateCount(), 1000)` to pass `this` to `updateCount`.